# Check the path of a running script on PBS job scheduler

Tags: linux, unix, hpc, pbs

I'd like to check where is the script which is currently running on my HPC platform. I know I can get the names of the jobs with the command `qsub`, which prompts:

```
                                                                                  Req'd  Req'd  
Job id               Username Queue    Name                 SessID NDS   TSK   Memory Time Us
-------------------- -------- -------- -------------------- ------ ----- ----- ------ ----- -
123456               xxxxx    xxxxxx    script_name         --         5   120     -- 72:00 R
```

**Update:** I managed to do it with UNIX commands: ´find´, ´cat´ and ´grep´, but I'd like to know if there is a way to get it directly from PBS commands.

*Old question: (for your information)*
Also, I know that the name is set inside the file with the variable

```
#SBATCH -J script_name
```

So I tried to look for it using ´find´, ´cat´ and ´grep´:

```
$ cat $(find . -name '*.sh') | grep script_name

#SBATCH -J script_name
```

But, of course, I'm getting just that line with that command

Is there a way to get the name/path of the file that owns the "grep-ed" file portion?

Is there a command to do it with the PBS commands (I'd love to know how to get it with the ´find´, ´cat´ and ´grep´ commands too)

Comment: I've managed to get the file name using `grep -l 'script_name' $(find . -name '*.sh')`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure which workload manager are you running. Commands you mentioned and the tag you added points to PBS but "SBATCH" in your script means that you are using SLURM.

I can tell you that in case of PBS job script is almost always in some directory under PBS_HOME directory on the execution host. You can find path of PBS_HOME in /etc/pbs.conf. The job directory is root protected directory so unless you are root, you can not see the contents.

The script name is not the name of the script you provide in the qsub command line utility. Rather, it is named after the job-id you get out of qsub and suffixed with ".SC".

Example, if `qsub job.sh` gives you a job id "7557.host1" then job script is named as "7557.host1.SC".